# Objective C: Unable to obtain Network Status value

Tags: objective-c, ios, networking, reachability

I am trying to get the network status via the following code

```
//define in my .h file
NetworkStatus internetConnectionStatus;

//define in my .m file
self.internetConnectionStatus = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]currentReachabilityStatus];
```

I am getting `self.internetconnection status = <null>`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the error you are getting. It's quite unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should compare the value of it to the enum values defined in `Reachability.h`:

```
if(self.internetConnectionStatus == NotReachable)
{
    // no connection
} else if(self.internetConnectionStatus == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
    // WiFi connection
} else if(self.internetConnectionStatus == ReachableViaWWAN)
{
    // 3G connection
}
```

Also, make sure your NetworkStatus has an `@property (nonatomic, assign)` for it in your header if you're using `self.` to get/set it.

In my opinion though, assuming you're using the Apple Reachability sample, it's not particularly refined and could possibly be giving an erroneous value in some circumstances. For a more robust version, use either the version that ships with the [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library, or the version which it is based on, which is available for download [here](http://blog.ddg.com/wp-content/uploads/blog.ddg.com/2010/02/Reachability-2.0.4ddg1.zip) and detailed in [this](http://blog.ddg.com/?p=24) blog post.